# How to integrate KeyPass2 and Chrome/Chromium in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, keepass, chrome-extension, add-on

I have already Installed KeePass2 and also installed Add-on. But I don't know how to integrate it. Pls help me with the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu > 18.04 - 20.04**
**Install KeyPass2:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start terminal and run following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install keepass2 mono-complete
```

Open Chrome, install [Kee - Password Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kee-password-manager/mmhlniccooihdimnnjhamobppdhaolme/related) Extension

[image: Kee]

Open as Administrator (Access), skip if you have it, if not follow the step.

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
nautilus -q
```

Download KeePassRPC plugins
[KeePassRPC.plgx](https://github.com/kee-org/keepassrpc/releases)

Right click plugins (/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins) folder select
"Open as Administrator"

Copy Paste the latest version of KeePassRPC into the plugins folder

```
/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins
```

You're all done!